# Killall Postgres stuck connections using Heroku Scheduler

Tags: python, postgresql, api, curl, heroku

I am using a Heroku Scheduler to schedule a restart for my dynos to prevent Heroku from doing it automatically at a time very inconvenient to my users using a curl command and a Heroku API token ( https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/platform-api-reference ) but I was wondering if I could also schedule a pg:killall using a curl command 30 min after the restart to clear any idle connections stuck in transaction [this always occurs during a restart]. Any ideas?

I've heard there is a way to implement a python .py script that can also take care of stuck connections but with my schema it would be a complicated route to go since Postgres in Heroku doesn't give it's users superuser access. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks,

Bobby

Comment: I recommend that you rather fix the application so that it closes connections properly.

Comment: Look, if the server is offline and we have IOT items in the field reporting to it, we will have stuck connections. This is not an issue with the coding. I believe before the cycle occurs I can blast out a websocket to all my endpoint to prevent them from sending messages for a time, but that's more work than needs to be done

Comment: Oh. In that case, set low TCP keepalive settings on the database server.